# Remove domain from a text

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, notepad

I have a list of domain name with parameters

```
http://www.anandinfra.net/project.php?id=2
http://artlinkinteriors.com/page.php?id=1
http://www.rabinmukherjeecollege.in/notice_details.php?id=1
```

I need to find other parts with domain and I have to replace those parts.

Finally my result should look as follows.
Expected result:

```
project.php?id=
page.php?id=
notice_details.php?id=
```

How can I attain this result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ > Search > Replace > Ensure `Regular Expression` is checked.

Find what: `http[s]?://.*/`

Replace with:

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me!